# The proper way of instanciating a list of objects

Tags: php, oop, design-patterns

I've always been wondering how i should write, and which design pattern to use in order to create lists of objects.

First of all, consider i have a Customer class and a Order class.
I would like to get all Orders that belongs to a User.

I'd like $oCustomer->getOrders(); to return an array of Order objects.

Basically, i've been thinking of :

An OrderManager class, which is a singleton and has the ability to retrieve Order data from the storage engine and build Order objects. But i've been reading everywhere that it's a bad practise, so that doesn't seem like a good idea.

Using static methods in the Order class, such as getOrders(args), but i'm not sure that's the real point of static methods.

Using a Factory (which i have never used, sadly) to handle object creation (i might need some examples there)

Using a method within an instanciated Order object. That seems like the worst option in the world, since i really don't think an object should be able to return a collection of itself.

This looks like a very basic task to do, which i guess it is. But i was not able to find anywhere someone giving the "proper" way to do so.
I'm OK with adding other classes and so (such as DataMappers,Gateways, aso... to handle retrieval and mapping) but i really don't want to have to talk with these in my buisness logic.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: since you didnt upvote or answer any of the existing answers can you please update your question with more details about what you are looking for in an answer. thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the [Lazy Load pattern from POEAA](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/lazyLoad.html):

[image: Lazy Load pattern from POEAA]

Note that there diagram does not suggest to place the logic to fetch the Orders from the database into the Customer object. Instead, the pattern suggests:

> There are four main varieties of lazy load. **Lazy Initialization** uses a special marker value (usually null) to indicate a field isn't loaded. Every access to the field checks the field for the marker value and if unloaded, loads it. **Virtual Proxy** is an object with the same interface as the real object. The first time one of its methods are called it loads the real the object and then delegates. **Value Holder** is an object with a getValue method. Clients call getValue to get the real object, the first call triggers the load. A **ghost** is the real object without any data. The first time you call a method the ghost loads the full data into its fields.

For additional patterns, consider [Repository](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/repository.html) and have a look at the [Data Source Architectural Patterns](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/index.html). In general, when you have lots of Object-Relational Behavioral problems, consider using an ORM, like Doctrine2.

Comment: @user1159791 Either pull in the full object graph when creating the customer or use Lazy Loading with any of the options mentioned above. Alternatively, inject a Orders Repository into Customers.

Answer (score 0):

You could use one class that represents the connection to the database, one data access object that uses this and one class for the actual object.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_access_object

Comment: Hi,
This might help retrieving data, but i'm not sure how this would let me build a list of objects, the problem stays the same.
If i understand well, the DAO will let me handle data storage, and mapping with my buisness object. But i would have to ask the DAO to create my object list, which i don't want. Plus i would have 1 DAO for each buisness object, that would rapidly become messy

Comment: In this design pattern the purpose of the DAO is indeed to return a list of objects. I don't know of any other way to properly separate data retrieval from the model. I would be interested in learning other ways to do this as well.

Comment: I just want to always have to use my buisness objects when i'm working on buisness logic. I need the abstraction of the data access layer to be completely eldued in the buisness logic of the application. Not sure if i'm clear. Maybe this is a very bad practise, really i don't know :s